# can I make facebook ask for all 3 permissions at once?

Tags: facebook, permissions

My facebook web app asks for three permissions when people sign up:

myapp would like to access your public profile and friend list.
myapp would like to post to your friends on your behalf.
myapp would like to manage your Pages.

Can I make the three permission  requests happen on the same page so the user does not have to step through three pages? BTW, I am not using   javascript, doing it by basic php header() calls.

Thanks